# Access denied when I try to open an R file

Tags: rstudio, access-denied, rscript

I just bought a new notebook with Windows 11. I downloaded and installed first R and after Rstudio. When I try to open a script previously created and perfectly working on my other 2 old laptops, I get the message "access denied".
I checked the permissions of each file i can't open through "property", and it seems ok.
Can someone help me with that?